# How can I disable the cache after receiving an error response from useFetch in Nuxt 3.8

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

If I run useFetch and receive 404 500...
After changing the page and returning to the original page, useFetch will not request again, the same information will remain.
But if I refresh the page, useFetch works correctly.

```js
const load = async () => {
  const { data, error, status } = await useFetch('http://server.test/api/test', {
    method: 'GET',
  });

  if (error.value) {
    console.log('error', error.value);
  }
};

load();
```

How do I disable this cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an error from the framework. Fix in Nuxt 3.8.1

https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/pull/23889 
https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/pull/23797

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Cache-Control` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control).

```
await useFetch('http://server.test/api/test', {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
  },
});
```